# Usage of 'If there’s a time’

Tags: word-choice, difference, clauses

Which one should be put in the blank?

> If there’s a time ..... the grammys favor white people, I hope it’s this time.

1. **that**
2. **when**
3. **where**

I have attempted to find the answer to this online but to no avail.

If multiple sentences I listed above are correct, what are the differences between them and in what situations would one be used over another?

I would also like to know what word class words like that, when, and where are.

Comment: Where did you see this test?

Comment: @Cardinal This wasn’t found in a test. I use this type of sentence regularly and was just wondering which word would be the most suitable in situations like this.

Comment: I would just use **when** here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a learner I think you can use **that** and **when**. However, there are two points:

Regarding the terminology, **that** is a [relative pronoun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/relative-pronouns), but I am not one hundred percent sure that if we can call **where** and **when** a relative pronoun as Cambridge claims. Generally, I think since **when** and **where** cannot act as the subject, it's not a good idea to call them relative pronoun.

I learned to call **when**, **where**, **after**, and so force [subordinate conjunction](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000377.htm) which are usually used to construct an adverbial clause.

In [defining relative clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining) you can use **that** instead of the relative pronouns **whom**, **who**, and **which** while you cannot do so in non-defining relative clauses.

So, I think the sentence can be considered as:

> *If there’s a time **which(that)** the grammys favor white people, I hope it’s this time.*

The other point is that replacing the relative pronoun with **that** makes the sentence less formal and it's more likely in conversations.